# React: How to add an infinite an infinite amount of components with onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and am building a form. The form consists of a collection made up of several Components. One of the Components is textfield.

I want to create a button that simply adds an infinite amount of the same textfield component on click. I'm stumped on how to do this and cannot find any information online.

My code thus far is:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleClickDestination = this.handleClickDestination.bind(this);
    }

    static defaultProps = {
    }

    static propTypes = {
    }

    handleClickDestination() {
      console.log('click');
    }

    render() {

      const {
        className
      } = this.props;

        return (
          <div className={className}>
           <DestinationSearchInput />
           <Grid item margin="normal">
           </Grid>
           <Grid container spacing={12} alignItems="flex-end">
             <Button onClick={this.handleClickDestination} color="primary">
                Add another destination
              </Button>
           </Grid>
           <div>
             // extra <DestinationSearchInput /> components to go here
           </div>
           <DatePicker />
           <TravellerCounter />
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: by `infinite` do you mean really infinite items? like with a `while(true)` clause or simply a `lot of some numbered items`  ?

Comment: @Prasanna on new component for each button click, so if they click the button 10 times I would like to see 10 new <DestinationSearchInput /> components.

Comment: check the answer and let me know if there are problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use states to let your component know how many destination fields are to be rendered

In this case I have just used an array of `dummy` items to render the fields for that many times.

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
     items: ['dummy']
  }
}
handleClickDestination() {
  this.setState({items: this.state.items.concat('dummy') })
}

render() {

  const {
    className
  } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={className}>
       <DestinationSearchInput />
       <Grid item margin="normal">
       </Grid>
       <Grid container spacing={12} alignItems="flex-end">
         <Button onClick={this.handleClickDestination} color="primary">
            Add another destination
          </Button>
       </Grid>
       <div>
       // use this block here
       { 
          this.state.items.map((_, index) => 
            <DestinationSearchInput 
               key={index}
            />
          ) 
       }
       // use this block here
       </div>
       <DatePicker />
       <TravellerCounter />
      </div>
    );
}
```

or simply use a number and then render using it

```
// in constructor
this.state = {items: 0}

// inside handle click
this.setState({items: this.state.items + 1})

// in render
new Array(this.state.items).fill(0).map((_,index) => 
    <DestinationSearchInput 
      key={index}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like:

```
onClick(){ this.setState({textFields: [...text}); onClick(); }
```

On the Render method, you can use:

```
const TextComponent = this.state.textFields.map(item => ... Your component here)
```

You can put random positions for your component as well.